# Unexpected Indentation in pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, indentation

When I run the following game I get an error "Unexpected Indent" but when you look at the code it's perfectly correct.

The error occurs at `del evilGuy[-1]`. The indentation is correct still I get this error.

## EDIT

The code has been changed a bit. Even now the error occurs at : `del evilGuy[-1]`  showing unexpected indentation.

```
def evilMove(evilGuy):
    evilCoords=[]
    #deadZones=[]
    #Returns either -1, 0 or 1
    randomMovex=random.randrange(-1,2)
    randomMovey=random.randrange(-1,2)
    newCell={'x':evilGuy[0]['x']+randomMovex,'y':evilGuy[0]['y']+randomMovey}
    if (newCell['x']<0 or newCell['y']<0 or newCell['x']>cellSize or newCell['y']>display_height/cellSize):
        newCell={'x':display_width/(2*cellSize),'y':display_height/(2*cellSize)

    del evilGuy[-1]
    
    evilCoords.append(newCell['x'])
    evilCoords.append(newCell['x'])
    deadZones.append(evilCoords)
    evilGuy.insert(0,newCell)
```

## Solved

The error was a missing '}' in the function evilMove.
Solutiuon is give below.

```
def evilMove(evilGuy):
    evilCoords=[]
    #deadZones=[]
    #Returns either -1, 0 or 1
    randomMovex=random.randrange(-1,2)
    randomMovey=random.randrange(-1,2)
    newCell={'x':evilGuy[0]['x']+randomMovex,'y':evilGuy[0]['y']+randomMovey}
    if (newCell['x']<0 or newCell['y']<0 or newCell['x']>cellSize or newCell['y']>display_height/cellSize):
        newCell={'x':display_width/(2*cellSize),'y':display_height/(2*cellSize)} # Here It's missing '}'

    del evilGuy[-1]

    evilCoords.append(newCell['x'])
    evilCoords.append(newCell['x'])
    deadZones.append(evilCoords)
    evilGuy.insert(0,newCell)
```

Comment: Did you maybe use Tabs and Spaces mixed?

Comment: I think @xXliolauXx right. For test this just copy your code lines it show you dots for space and a line for tab.

Comment: @xXliolauXx  , No i havent mixed the tabs and spaces.The above code is exactly what i have in my code.

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` on the `newCell ={...` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pb exist from the number of white space
in your code delete the space before def, and add three space before ''', your code will be (just copy and paste) :

```
def evilMove(evilGuy): # here delete spaces 
    evilCoords=[]
    #deadZones=[]
    #Returns either -1, 0 or 1
    randomMovex=random.randrange(-1,2)
    randomMovey=random.randrange(-1,2)
    newCell={'x':evilGuy[0]['x']+randomMovex,'y':evilGuy[0]['y']+randomMovey}
    '''  # here add spaces
    if (newCell['x']<0 or newCell['y']<0 or newCell['x']>cellSize or newCell['y']>display_height/cellSize):
        newCell={'x':display_width/(2*cellSize),'y':display_height/(2*cellSize)

    '''
    del evilGuy[-1]                 
    evilGuy.insert(0,newCell)
```